# Is there a function script to find and go to the column by header title?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need a button script that will go to a specific column on the same row as the active cell but by header name and not just by relative coordinates.  When I add a column to the table the script goes to one column off. It needs to go to the specific column and not just 15 columns over from the active cell.

This is what I have but it jumps to 02 (the first column of my range) and then AU2 since that is what I selected in my macro recording. Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

```
function Reasons_To_Selector1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 41).activate();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const hr = 1;
  const sr = 2;
  const [hdr, ...vs] = sh.getRange(hr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - hr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  const idx = {};//idx return idx into row for each header string
  hdr.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; });
  let o = vs.map((r, i) => {
    let x = r[idx["COL1"]];
    if (r[idx["COL1"]] % 2 == 0) {
      r[idx["COL1"]] = '';
      r.splice([idx["COL1"]],"");
      return r;
    } else {
      return r;
    } 
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

Sheet0:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 6 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 7 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 8 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 9 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 10 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 11 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 12 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 13 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 14 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 15 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 16 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 17 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 18 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 19 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 20 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| 21 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| 22 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |
| 23 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| 24 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 |
| 25 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 |
| 26 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 |

o:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
|  | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
|  | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
|  | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
|  | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
|  | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
|  | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
|  | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
|  | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
|  | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |
|  | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 |
|  | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 |
| 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 |